# Is there a way to use message.member.voiceChannel.join() in direct messages?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I have been researching discord.js v11 to make a (user) bot, and I cant seem to use message.member.voiceChannel.join() in DM's. I know this isnt possible for normal bots but it may be possible for user accounts. Is there a way?

Comment: User account botting is against Discord TOS, so why would DJS support a user-exclusive feature?

Comment: Im just wondering, not gonna do it though

Comment: Not possible using just discord.js. Discord.js does not support features for regular user accounts, which of course is against Discord ToS and it is unadvisable to attempt to do this. Regardless, `message.member.voiceChannel.join()` would not work for you anyways because `message.member` returns a `GuildMember` object, and obviously DM channels are not guilds.